# Entity Framework 6 load derived class of entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework 6, given `class A` and derived `class B: A`, I would like to load entities `A` into instances of `B` without having to code for each property.

So given:

```
public class A
{
   public Guid AId { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class B: A
{
   [NotMapped]
   public string OtherValue { get; set; }
}

public MyDbContext: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
   IEnumerable<B> Bs = db.As.LoadBsSomehow()
}
```

I'm guessing I could add `DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }` and then in `OnModelCreate` I could override the table name to `As` perhaps.  I'd like to avoid that if I can.

The purpose of doing this is that we need view models that need the underlying model plus some other properties and I don't want to mess up the models with all the different view model properties.  This would simplify coding and maintenance for when the main model is changed -- the inheritance would automatically handle the changes in the derived class (view models).

I can then set the additional properties of the `Bs` in a `Select` or other method.

Also, I do NOT want to use reflection.  I can code that up if I need it.  I'd rather find out if EF 6 has the ability to do this natively.

UPDATE: I can do `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>`.  I would prefer to be able to use LINQ instead of writing SQL.  I have no problem writing SQL, but LINQ is much more maintainable from a code perspective.  Perhaps if I can use LINQ to create an `IQueryable<B>` and get the SQL for it?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: db.As.OfType<B>.ToList()

Comment: @JonathanMagnan - No, that just filters based on a type.  I actually want to convert the A's to B's.  They will come back as A's by default, but I'd like instances of B to be populated instead of the base class A instances.  I can't Cast() because the instances (at least coming back from db.DbSet<A> queries) aren't actually B's.  They are A's, and since the underlying instance is the base class, I can't cast to the derived class.